# ¿Como puedo saber todas las clases que estan extendidas a otra clase abstracta?

Tags: java

*Hola a todos* **JAVA**

Bueno, estos últimos días estuve trabajando en un proyecto de un juego y algunos me pidieron que implemente un tipo de "API" para que ellos puedan hacer sus propios "JUGADORES", ejemplo:

```
public class ejemplo extends MakeAPlayer{}
```

"MakeAPlayer" contiene métodos abstractos que ellos deben de llenar (@Override), pero nunca puedo registrar su clase en mi plugin, hay alguna forma?, Puede ser que funcione con un HashSet en un constructor?, ***Gracias al que responda!***

Answer (score 2):

Si no he entendido mal, deberás hacer-les una pregunta a los objetos, tu código quedaría así:

```
class Animal {}
class Perro extends Animal {
   public static void main (String[] args){
     Perro toby = new Perro();
     if (toby instanceof Animal)
       System.out.println("toby es un perro y también un animal");
   }
}
```

De esta manera con el `instanceof` sabes si extienden de una clase u otra, dónde yo tengo `Animal` tu pondrás la clase que te interese como `MakeAPlayer`.

Espero haver-te ayudado, sino ya sabes, coméntamelo.

Sigo con tu comentario:

Entonces lo que tu necesitas es una creación de una clase genérica dónde ésta será un subtipo de tu clase `MakeAPlayer`.

Un ejemplo de código podría ser así:

```
 Person p = new Person();   

Class<? extends Person> clase = p.getClass();  

try {  
    Person p =  clase.newInstance();  
} catch (InstantiationException e) {  
    System.out.println(p.getName() + " no puede ser instanciada");  
    System.out.println("Puede ser que " + p.getName() + " sea una clase abstracta," +  
        " una interfaz, un vector (array), a primitive type, or void;");          
    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {  
    System.out.println("La clase " + p.getName() + "no tiene un constructor " +   
        "vacío y público");  
        e.printStackTrace();  
} // try
```

Te dejo una fuente de información dónde explica de una forma sintetizada lo que necesitas. 
http://personales.unican.es/sanchezbp/teaching/faqs/genericsJava.html

[java](/questions/tagged/java)

Comment: Hola, eso lo se, pero lo que estoy buscando es una buena forma para registrar una clase de otro plugin en mi plugin, por eso estoy creando una API, Ejemplo ellos a la hora de hacer su clase la extendien a "MakeAPlayer" por ejemplo, pero yo nunca voy a saber el nombre de su clase, yo no puedo saber que se llama "toby", en otras palabras, la funcion de mi plugin seria obtener automaticamente la clase extendida "MakeAPlayer" y registrarla en el plugin, Lo que estoy buscando seria mas en un contructor, osea, cuando el plugin carga automatica mente registre la clase esta en mi plugin.

Comment: Si te fijas, aquí no necesitas saber el nombre de la clase que va a extender de "MakeAPlayer".

Comment: @sakulino en el código que presentas, sí necesitas saber el nombre de la clase en tiempo de compilación. Está en la primera línea: `Persona p = new Persona();`. Lo que se necesita es algo aún más abstracto: deberías llamar al ClassLoader y ver que las clases que está cargando o que ha cargado extienden a la clase que va a registrar el plugin. O en todo caso obtener las clases a cargar desde un archivo o algún otro mecanismo para luego automatizar la lectura y procesamiento de los mismos.

Comment: Entonces debe recurrir a la programación reflexiva, cuando llegue a casa buscaré algunos ejemplos en los que la puse en práctica. Gracias @Luiggi Mendoza.